# Read value in rocksdb in chunks

Tags: c++, rocksdb

I want to read a really huge value stored in rocksdb. Is it possible to read it part by part?
Like reading a file's content into a fixed buffer...

for example I have a 500 MB value, that is a zlib-compressed file. as this is a server program, I can't allocate 500 MB to every connection ( 500 MB for value, that may be more anyway, and SSL context, authentication info, etc...).

And also, this values have a meaning to protocol so I can't part it up.
According to documentation, value size must be smaller than 3GB. I don't think any server program allocate this size for a single connection.

I can mention some examples that can be usefull:

1. making a filesystem on top of RocksDB
2. Storing sounds, images, videos,... in a messaging app

Suppose such an example:

```cpp
Slice partialSlice;
db->Get(opt,"ac154df568bb874", &partialSlice, 256*1024);  /// read 256KB at once
socket.write(partialSlice.data(), 256*1024);
while(partialSlice.HaveRemaining) {
   /// repate it to get all of data...
}
```

Comment: What is the size of _that_ value? According to the documentation, [_value size must be smaller than 4GB_](https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/wiki/Basic-Operations#reads-and-writes). You need to add more context to your problem. Add your relevant code too.

Comment: Check the `PinnableSlice` in the link in my comment. That's more relevant to your problem. That link leads to [this](https://rocksdb.org/blog/2017/08/24/pinnableslice.html) which is more detailed and looks like it's what you need.

Comment: You can create chunks from this and process those - in-place or after creating duplicates. Check the [example](https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/blob/master/examples/simple_example.cc). Let me know if this solves your problem so that I can post a consolidated answer.

Comment: Unfortunately no. I think I must chunk it to 256KB parts for example, and use prefix scan to rebuild value up. Is this the reason for existence of prefix scan? Am I answering my own question? Does using this criteria increase space usage because of multiple keys?

Comment: Isn't that a bit different from your original question? From your comment, what I understand is that you plan to divide to the same data in fixed size chunks under multiple keys with a common prefix (e.g. `testkey1`, `testkey2`, ..., `testkeyN`). Is that correct? According to your question, the 500MB would now be divided into multiple chunks.

Comment: Yes that is correct. I have no other way. I tried to ask this question from one of rocksdb's developers but it seems there is no such an API.

Comment: Why can't you use `PinnableSlice`? That looks like the perfect solution in this scenario. Simply, get a slice of the key, process it in chunks (no memory overhead) and you're done.

Comment: Another solution could be: Store the path of the compressed file against the key, retrieve it whenever required and process that. The latency here needs to be measured in case of disk I/O of the file and the in-memory version from the DB.

Comment: Yeah. Actually I wanna to save the file in db because of disk overhead of seeking, reading,.... DB can moderate it. Post both recent comments as answer. :-)

Comment: Is `PinnableSlice` working? Which ones: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60470028/read-value-in-rocksdb-in-chunks#comment106979991_60470028) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60470028/read-value-in-rocksdb-in-chunks#comment106980020_60470028)?

Comment: PinnableSlice doesn't do that all the time. If it can't do that, it will retrieve all of data at once. Yes, post both in one post, to see others opinion...

Comment: Sure. If you could update your question by adding the relevant code from your problem that would be very helpful also.

Comment: Question: For your filesystem stuff, are you using [FileSystem](https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/blob/86f1ad7046dc829f501581c48123078748825795/include/rocksdb/file_system.h#L150) or doing it yourself using simple Put/Get/Delete APIs?

Comment: it will be like a Git repository. any file have a hash and the key is the file's hash. value is its content. in a simple word.

Answer (score 1):

Check [PinnableSlice](https://rocksdb.org/blog/2017/08/24/pinnableslice.html). It seems to be a good solution for this scenario.

Simply, get a slice of the value, process it in chunks (no memory overhead; refer limitations section) and you're done. Maybe, you already have a function that accepts the raw memory for decompression to avoid memory overhead for input data.

---

An alternative solution could be:

Store the path/handle of the compressed file against the key, retrieve it whenever required and process that. The latency here needs to be measured in case of disk I/O of the file and the in-memory version from the DB.